# Can I record a video without using UIImagePickerController?

Tags: iphone, ffmpeg

Can I record a video without using UIImagePickerController?
Of course without needing to jailbreak or anything else that would cause the App Store to reject the app.

I think there is a way to access video device not using UIImagePickerController because these camera applications can record video and work on iPhone 2G/3G which utilizes ffmpeg:

- [iVideoCamera](http://itunes.apple.com/app/ivideocamera-record-video/id332166209?mt=8)
- [iVidCam](http://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewSoftware?id=309681127&mt=8&ign-mpt=uo%3D6)

I pick  this code up by googling.

```
AVFormatParameters formatParams;
AVInputFormat *iformat;

formatParams.device = "/dev/video0";
formatParams.channel = 0;
formatParams.standard = "ntsc";
formatParams.width = 640;
formatParams.height = 480;
formatParams.frame_rate = 29;
formatParams.frame_rate_base = 1;
filename = "";
iformat = av_find_input_format("video4linux");

av_open_input_file(&ffmpegFormatContext,
                 filename, iformat, 0, &formatParams);
```

This code tell me how to open camera device, but I don't know device path of iPhone.

How do iVideoCamera and iVidCam record video?

Answer (score 0):

Both of these use CoreSurface which is a private API. You can google it for more information. In iOS 4, there are new API's to get direct frame access from the camera.